# Teradata SQL - String Similarity between Rows/Records

Tags: string, teradata, rows, similarity

i am currently working on a question regarding string similarity in Teradata SQL that I cannot get my head around. Scenario is the following:

In my table, I have one column, say "names" with real names, most often composed of forename and surname. I want to compare the similarity of strings (i.e. names) between different records.

Simple case example:

record 1: tom jones
record 2: t jones
record 3: tom jo

This should give a high similarity.

Complex case example:

record 1: tom jones
record 2: t jones
record 3: tom jo
record 4: billy bob
record 5: billy
record 6: bob

This should give a high similarity AND identify two different names/groups.

I was thinking about using xmlagg to get the rows into a single cell, then unpack to get the single cell into columns and then use the Teradata string similarity function on the resulting columns. But that didnt seem reasonable to me because in some cases I have >1000 names/ records to compare -> many columns etc...

I would highly appreciate your support to identifying any general approachof how to slice this elefant...

Many thanks
FJ

Comment: this probably cannot be done in SQL alone, even with Teradata's rich syntax. You better extract the data and use your language of choice. One way is to calculate lexical distance and partition (liely O(N2) complexity), another way is to try to construct some common parent string P of 2 similar strings A&B, such that A and B are both P's subsequence. (or coversely get some common child) Then let P act as a representation of the cluster to reduce your computation to O(N) or O(NlogN)

Comment: The `StringSimilarity` function operates pairwise so it seems to me you would need to cross join the table with itself (possibly excluding the case where record IDs are equal) and pass the resulting pair(s) of columns to calculate the similarity values

Comment: `StringSimilarity` is supported on the latest Teradata releases, "16.20 Feature Update 2"+, before it's only available on the MLE-Engine or Aster. Two other/simpler functions exists, `editdistance` & `ngram`, but it will be hard to find an algorithm to match your expected result.